# jni problems when system load the .so file

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I have already created .so file and put it in proper path.
However,when I try to run the android program the problem came by.
the problem is:

```
`5-16 15:34:16.704: E/AndroidRuntime(9968): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
Cannot load library: reloc_library[1311]:  1584 cannot locate '_Z13raptor_decodePKhtPKtPhjPK15RaptorParam_tag'...
```

raptor_decode is a function which included by the jni_function.`

what should i do to correct this problem? Thanks.

Comment: trying exporting the location of your library in LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: you can check the package name in the jni header file. It should match with that of your java class file from where you are calling jni functions

Comment: @sachy The unresolved reference clearly isn't a native Java method.

Comment: @EJP java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError kind of error comes while working with .so files. Thats why i suggested to look in the header.

Comment: @sachy That particular Unsatisfiedalink error names a native C function, not a JNI method. It has nothing to do with the package name or the header of any JNI method.

Comment: @jogabonito what is LD_LIBRARY_PATH?~

Comment: @sachy The unresolved reference isn't a native Java method.It is a method which called by native Java method.

Comment: @EJP how can I solve this problem? the unresolved reference is a method which called by native Java method.the declaration of this method is in the .h file

Comment: @user1398037 Find the .so library where it is implemented and name its location in `java.library.path`.

Comment: @EJP I do all this work in linux environment and use NDK. so I don't think there would be something wrong with the path problem.And I could not find java.library.path~~ I already use the system.getpropert("java.library.path").but in the path which is showed I can not find it~ what should I do?~

Comment: @user1398037 What you think is immaterial. Your software doesn't work, ergo you have made some mistake, ergo something about your thinking or its execution is wrong. The problem of the unresolved symbol remains, and it is because the .so containing the definition of that symbol cannot be found. This is the problem you need to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is your problem:

```
1584 cannot locate '_Z13raptor_decodePKhtPKtPhjPK15RaptorParam_tag'
```

if raptor_decode is the method you want to call, read up here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/design.html (and read up 11.3)

Comment: now I know the reason of the problem, but how can I solve it?~~

Comment: how can I solve this problem? the unresolved reference is a method which called by native Java method.the declaration of this method is in the .h file